# Shortcode plugin not recognizing line breaks in regex

Tags: php, regex, joomla

I am using a Joomla shortcode plugin which hunts out shortcode codes and replaces them with html content. It works well, that is, until the user inserts a linebreak at which point it fails. I believe it is something to do with the regex but knowing almost nothing about regex I cant see what. Here is the regex that finds my shortcode...

```
"tab"=>array("codeHolder"=>"[LOFG-TAB-HOLDER-%d]",
"codeCheck"=>"[BStabs",
"codeModifier"=>"#\[BStabs(.*?)\](.*?)\[/BStabs\]#e",
"codeMakeHolder"=>"'[LOFG-TAB-HOLDER-' . PlgSystemIceShortCodes::getCount('tab') . ']'",
"regex"=>'/\[BStabs(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/BStabs\]/im')
```

I need the regex to recognize/ignore line breaks in the inputted shortcode - how is this done?

Comment: It might be best you contact the developer of the plugin as it's related to their own extension

Comment: I would usually but since it's a free plugin and I am modifying it I doubt that that's going to prove helpful. I think I might have found a solution anyway.

Comment: Just to see if it even has any effect, try replacing all the `.*?` with `[\s\S]*?` (and brace for horrendous results). Maybe try it just on the `regex` first, _e.g._ `"regex"=>'/\[BStabs([\s\S]*?)\]([\s\S]*?)\[\/BStabs\]/im'`

Comment: Awesome that fixed it - you should post this as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the regex patterns allow you to post the full regex including modifiers

To make the dot (.) character match newlines, you simply need to add the s flag, eg

`"regex"=>'/\[BStabs(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/BStabs\]/sim'`